# Active Directory membership provider using LDAP

Tags: asp.net, azure, active-directory, ldap, membership-provider

I am working on a school assignment where we handle logins to a web application written in asp.NET using Active Directory. Our Active Directory is installed on a virtual machine on Azure.

When trying to login, I am presented with the following error: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B36g8.png]

I have checked my connection string multiple times, and can't seem to get it to work.

Currently, I have the following connection string:

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ictforevents1.cloudapp.net/DC=ictforevents1,DC=cloudapp,DC=net" />
```

The DNS name assigned to our virtual machine is ictforevents1.cloudapp.net, which is also the domain I set up in the Active Directory setup wizard.

Using the data in the connection string above, I can connect to the AD using LDAP Admin.

How to fix the error?

Comment: are you running the web app and the ldap admin from the same machine?

Comment: @CosminOnea yes, the asp application is being run from the same machine as ldap Admin. I use vs 2013 for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing the domain with the IP address in the connection string. From what I could find, asp will always always try to use a secure connection, even when using the insecure port (389). It will not attempt this when an IP address is given.

My new connection string is:

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://23.97.173.160:389/CN=Users,DC=ictforevents1,DC=cloudapp,DC=net" />
```

While this is not ideal, because the server does not have a static IP, it's better than not working at all.

Comment: Mind that you need to remove the port from the connection string before the role provider works [Like I mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30851785/4385713)